# Boost::tribool: odd behaviour, or bug?

Tags: c++, boost, tribool

I'm exploring [boost::tribool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/tribool.html) and was surprised by the following behaviour.

```
{
using namespace boost;

boost::tribool t(indeterminate);

assert(t==indeterminate);  // This assertion fails!
}
```

However, if I do this, the assert passes.

```
assert(indeterminate(t));
```

No compiler warnings or errors in either case. Anyone have a good explanation of why this should be??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/logic/operator___id623512.html):

the result of comparing two indeterminate values is indeterminate (not true) - we don't know what the values are, so we can't tell that they are equal;

the [indeterminate](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/logic/indeterminate.html) function can be used to test if a tribool is in an indeterminate state.

Comment: And since indeterminate converts implicitly to bool false, the assert fails.

Comment: "the result of comparing two indeterminate values is indeterminate". Ouch. I guess that makes sense at one level, but it's not intuitive to me.

Comment: @Roddy, look at implementation of tribool::operator==()
are u ready? it returns tribool!
I hate the guy who submitted this code to boost :D
+1 for good question, this is NOT intuitive behavior!

Comment: @HovhannesGrigoryan once you learn to deal with indeterminate values (`R` is an example of a language which has them for all types), you realize that this is the only option that makes sense